# Recycler view data not loading on screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to show the recycler view's data on my app. The thing is, even though the NetworkStatus is successful (I can tell because I don't get the toast's message and the loader disappears and I can also see the data in the logcat), the info is not displayed. I am not sure if the error is in the way I'm calling the recycler view on my MainActivity or in the RecyclerAdapter but any idea as to where the problem is would be very helpful.

This is the RecyclerAdapter:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.app.mortyapp.databinding.ItemDetailBinding

class RecyclerAdapter(private var characterList: List<Character>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ItemDetailBinding.inflate(
            layoutInflater,
            parent,
            false
        )
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = characterList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(characterList[position])
    }

    fun setCharacterList(characterList: List<Character>){
        this.characterList = characterList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(
        private val binding: ItemDetailBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        fun bind(character: Character) {
            with(binding){
                val itemName: TextView = binding.tvName
                val itemGender: TextView = binding.tvGender

                itemName.text = character.name
                itemGender.text = character.gender
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the MainActivity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.app.mortyapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var  binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val characters = mutableListOf<Character>()
    private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var recyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels(
        factoryProducer = {MainViewModelFactory()}
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        progressBar = binding.ProgressBar
        progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        setObservers()
        initRecyclerView()

    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        with(binding.rvCharacters){
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(characters).apply {
                setCharacterList(characters)
            }
        }
    }


    private fun setObservers(){
        viewModel.characterList.observe(this, Observer {
            when(it.status){
                NetworkStatus.LOADING ->{
                    //show loading state
                    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                NetworkStatus.SUCCESS -> {
                    //hide loading state
                    progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    //render character list
                    recyclerAdapter.setCharacterList(characters)

                }
                NetworkStatus.ERROR -> {
                    //show error message
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error loading content", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //hide loading state
                    progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

API response:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class Character (
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @SerializedName("gender") val gender: String
)

data class CharacterListResponse(
    @SerializedName("results") val results: List<Character>
)
```

Remote data source:

```
package com.app.mortyapp

import com.app.mortyapp.Model.CharacterService
import com.app.mortyapp.Model.RetrofitServices
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class CharacterRemoteDataSource {
    fun getCharacterList(networkResponse: NetworkResponse<List<Character>>) {
        val service = RetrofitServices.instance
            .create(CharacterService::class.java)
            .getCharacterList()

        service.enqueue(object : Callback<CharacterListResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<CharacterListResponse>,
                response: Response<CharacterListResponse>
            ) {
                val resource = response.body()?.run {
                    if (results.isNotEmpty())
                        Resource(NetworkStatus.SUCCESS, results)
                    else
                        Resource(NetworkStatus.ERROR)
                } ?: run {
                    Resource(NetworkStatus.ERROR)
                }
                networkResponse.onResponse(resource)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<CharacterListResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                networkResponse.onResponse(Resource(NetworkStatus.ERROR, message = t.message))
            }
        })
    }


}

interface NetworkResponse<T> {
    fun onResponse(value: Resource<T>)
}
```

Comment: could not see any problem in the above code, did you make sure that in the NetworkStatus.SUCCESS you are getting the character list successfully, might be it is just a parsing issue.

Comment: @GauravBansal I'm following a tutorial to set it all up and it made sense the way it was done, I added the remote data source here just in case something is wrong with it and I can't tell

Comment: can you do debug or put logs into your setCharacterList function to check what is the size of character list which you received and the content as well, to check if that's right.

Comment: @GauravBansal I added Log.d("CHARACTER LIST SIZE: ", "$characterList.size") to the function and I got D/CHARACTER LIST SIZE:: [].size .. why is it not getting it is what I don't get, since I can see that the retrofit request is working in the logs but the adapter doesn't seem to be getting any. Any ideas?

Comment: you are getting response from the server but your parsing is getting failed. Can you show me how you are creating the retrofit instance, did you add GsonFactory into Retrofit builder ?

Answer (score 1):

Set adapter for Recyclerview in

```
setupRecylerview ()

adapter = recyclerAdapter

NetworkStatus.SUCCESS -> {
                    //hide loading state
                    progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    //render character list
                    recyclerAdapter.setCharacterList(characters)

                    recyclerAdapter.notifydatasetchanged()//add this line 

                }
```

Comment: sadly that doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

I think most problems found with recyclerView isn't linked to it, but with some adjourning codes. For example, a very similar problem was solved by finding out that the adapter POJO class was retrieving 0 rather than the actual size of the array list.

See the solved problem here:
[Android Recycler View not loading Data (Peculiar problem, Not a Duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73253158/android-recycler-view-not-loading-data-peculiar-problem-not-a-duplicate)